# Is there a better way to use barcode scanner?

Tags: c#, uwp, barcode-scanner

I'm currently using using a `BarcodeScanner` in UWP App.
To implement it I followed some tutorials on Microsoft docs.

It's working fine but not like I want it to work.

The barcode scanner can only get the value through a `DataReceived` event.
So when I want to return a value from a `BarcodeScanner`, it's impossible.

Here I'm registering the scanner :

```cs
private static async Task<bool> ClaimScanner()
{
    bool res = false;

    string selector = BarcodeScanner.GetDeviceSelector();
    DeviceInformationCollection deviceCollection = await 
    DeviceInformation.FindAllAsync(selector);

    if (_scanner == null)
        _scanner = await BarcodeScanner.FromIdAsync(deviceCollection[0].Id);

    if (_scanner != null)
    {
        if (_claimedBarcodeScanner == null)
            _claimedBarcodeScanner = await _scanner.ClaimScannerAsync();

        if (_claimedBarcodeScanner != null)
        {
            _claimedBarcodeScanner.DataReceived += ClaimedBarcodeScanner_DataReceivedAsync;
            [...] 
        }
    }
}
```

And once I'm receiving data it triggers that event :

```cs
private static async void ClaimedBarcodeScanner_DataReceivedAsync(ClaimedBarcodeScanner sender, BarcodeScannerDataReceivedEventArgs args)
{
    await Windows.ApplicationModel.Core.CoreApplication.MainView.CoreWindow.Dispatcher.RunAsync(CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal, () =>
    {
        if (CurrentDataContext != null && CurrentDataContext is IScannable)
        {
            IScannable obj = (IScannable)CurrentDataContext;
            obj.NumSerie = CryptographicBuffer.ConvertBinaryToString(BinaryStringEncoding.Utf8, args.Report.ScanDataLabel);
        }
        else if (CurrentDataContext != null && CurrentDataContext is Poste)
        {
            Poste p = (Poste)CurrentDataContext;
            string code = CryptographicBuffer.ConvertBinaryToString(BinaryStringEncoding.Utf8, args.Report.ScanDataLabel);
            p.CodePoste = code.Substring(0, 6);
        }
    });
}
```

And as you can see I'm kind of forced to do everything in that method (updating instances of others classes, etc.).

Currently I'm calling the BarcodeScanner like that in the ViewModel :

```cs
public void ScanPosteCodeAsync()
{
    BarcodeScannerUtil.ScanBarcodeUtil(CurrentPoste);
}
```

But I have no control of my `CurrentPoste` instance and what I would do is more like :

```cs
public void ScanPosteCodeAsync()
{
    string returnedCode = BarcodeScannerUtil.ScanBarcodeUtil()
    this.CurrentPoste.Code = returnedCode;
}
```

Is there any way to return the value of the scanner in order to use the returned value in my ViewModel ?

Comment: Well a similar pattern exists for WPF devs when using MVVM and you need to get/update the models that your VM is exposing.  Perhaps they are in a database.  Rather than pollute your nice VM with ugly DB code, a _"service"_ can be passed into the VM.  Now, "serivce" doesn't necessarily mean SOA/microservices, maybe its just another class in a different project.  The point is you put all your barcode stuff there and when something is received, perhaps it fires an event that your VM listens to or perhaps it just queues it up somewhere ready for your VM to request via the service interface

Comment: I already have all the barcode code in a service class, and there's the problem because I don't want the service class to update my current model.
The major issue I have is that I don't know how to do to make my VM listen to the `DataReceived` event.

Comment: Well, from what I can see your service is not decoupled from UWP MVVM.  For the event, have you considered exposing a secondary event purely for the VM client?  I find that works well for me

Comment: Like an event in the VM listening to the data received event ?

Answer (score 3):

Well a similar pattern exists for WPF devs when using MVVM and you need to get/update the models that your view model (VM) is exposing. Perhaps they are in a database. Rather than pollute your nice VM with ugly DB code, a "service" can be passed into the VM. Now, "serivce" doesn't necessarily mean SOA/microservices, maybe its just another class in a different project. The point is you put all your barcode stuff there and when something is received, perhaps it fires an event that your VM listens to or perhaps it just queues it up somewhere ready for your VM to request via the service interface.

> I already have all the barcode code in a service class, and there's the problem because I don't want the service class to update my current model. The major issue I have is that I don't know how to do to make my VM listen to the DataReceived event

Well, from what I can see your service is not decoupled from UWP MVVM. For the event, have you considered exposing a secondary event purely for the VM client? I find that works well for me.

> Like an event in the VM listening to the data received event ?

Yes, but it doesn't have to be a listending to a physical `event` type just the concept.  C# events imply that can be more than one subscriber which doesn't really make sense for barcode apps.  There should only be one foreground reader.

Here I shall use `Action<string>` to pass the barcode from `BarcodeScanner` to the client, in this case the VM.  By using an `Action` and moving the barcode processing to the client we keep the `BarcodeScanner` completely unaware of MVVM.  `Windows.ApplicationModel.Core.CoreApplication.MainView` was making `BarcodeScanner` incredibly coupled to stuff it shouldn't care about.

First of all we want to decouple everything so first up is an interface representing the important bits of the barcode scanner:

```
public interface IBarcodeScanner
{
    Task<bool> ClaimScannerAsync();
    void Subscribe(Action<string> callback);
    void Unsubscribe();
}
```

With that defined we shall pass it into your VM like so:

```
public class MyViewModel 
{
    private readonly IBarcodeScanner _scanner;

    /// <summary>
    /// Initializes a new instance of the <see cref="MyViewModel"/> class.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="scanner">The scanner, dependency-injected</param>
    public MyViewModel(IBarcodeScanner scanner)
    {
        // all business logic for scanners, just like DB, should be in "service"
        // and not in the VM

        _scanner = scanner;
    }
```

Next we add some command handlers.  Imagine we have a button that when clicked, kicks off   a barcode subscription.  Add the following to the VM:

```
public async void OnWidgetExecuted()
{
    await _scanner.ClaimScannerAsync();
    _scanner.Subscribe(OnReceivedBarcode);
}

// Barcode scanner will call this method when a barcode is received
private void OnReceivedBarcode(string barcode)
{
    // update VM accordingly
}
```

Finally, the new look for the `BarcodeScanner`:

```
public class BarcodeScanner : IBarcodeScanner
{
    /// <summary>
    /// The callback, it only makes sense for one client at a time
    /// </summary>
    private static Action<string> _callback; // <--- NEW

    public async Task<bool> ClaimScannerAsync()
    {
        // as per OP's post, not reproduced here
    }

    public void Subscribe(Action<string> callback) // <--- NEW
    {
        // it makes sense to have only one foreground barcode reader client at a time
        _callback = callback;
    }

    public void Unsubscribe() // <--- NEW
    {
        _callback = null;
    }

    private void ClaimedBarcodeScanner_DataReceivedAsync(ClaimedBarcodeScanner sender, BarcodeScannerDataReceivedEventArgs args)
    {
        if (_callback == null) // don't bother with ConvertBinaryToString if we don't need to
            return;

        // all we need do here is convert to a string and pass it to the client

        var barcode = CryptographicBuffer.ConvertBinaryToString(BinaryStringEncoding.Utf8,
                                                                args.Report.ScanDataLabel);

        _callback(barcode);

    }
}
```

### So what was the problem?

In summary you sort of got yourself caught up in somewhat of a circular dependency problem whereby the VM depended on the `BarcodeScanner` and the `BarcodeScanner` depended on presentation APIs - something it shouldn't need to know about.  Even with the good attempt at abstractions you had in the `BarcodeScanner` with regards to `IScannable` (sadly not a case with `Poste`), the scanning layer is making assumptions as to the type of users using it.  It was just to *vertical*.

With this new approach you could very use it for other types of apps including UWP console apps if you needed to.

Comment: That looks a lot better than what I did. Thanks a lot for your detailed answer, I understand it way better now.
I'll try it out as soon as I can and will give you feedback.

Comment: @Reaperino you are welcome good sir.  I meant to reply to you earlier today but I forgot sadly (plus I really needed to be in front of VS).  All the best!

Comment: Hello, I have a little question about the code.
I'm understanding pretty much everything except the part with the `IBarcodeScanner` in the view model's constructor.
How is the `IBarcodeScanner` instance actually created ? Like is it the view model locator that is doing it ?

Comment: @Reaperino If you are using dependency injection then refer to doco on how to setup lifetimes.  If you aren't or don't want to inject in the constructor, you can just create it manually and set a property on the VM.  The easiest thing to do is via the view's code-behind and set the VM's property.  But there are many ways